# C++ Multiple Inheritance Triangle

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Is there an issue with such an inheritance tree:

```
Parent ---- Subject
|         /
|        /
Child --/
```

Or in code:

```
class Subject
{
public:
    void AddObserver( Observer *aObserver );
protected:
    ObserversList mObserversList;
};

class Parent: public Object,
              public virtual Subject
{
};

class Child: public Parent,
             public virtual Subject
{
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation-wise there is **no issue** with this kind of inheritance. As both the bases coming to `Child` are `virtual` inherited.

The only thing one must know is that, while *constructing* `Parent()`, the order of construction will be `Subject()` followed by `Object()`. Same thing is applicable for `Child()`. The order will be `Subject()`, `Object()`, `Parent()`.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, `Child` will only have a 'single' Subject interface. Also, would the answer remain the same if I don't use `virtual` with `public Subject`?

Comment: @Izhaki, Yes, `Child` will have only one `Subject` base inside it, which is first to be constructed. No, things won't be same if you remove `virtual` from either `Parent` or `Child`. Some compilers may support having just one `virtual` inheritance, but that's not allowed by standard. All the `Subject` coming towards `Child` **must** be `virtual` inherited.